# Selecting X words from a text field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm building a basic search functionality, using LIKE (I'd be using fulltext but can't at the moment) and I'm wondering if MySQL can, on searching for a keyword (e.g. WHERE field LIKE '%word%') return 20 words either side of the keyword, as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all in the query using SUBSTRING_INDEX

```
CONCAT_WS(
' ',
-- 20 words before
TRIM(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING(field, 1, INSTR(field, 'word') - 1 ),
        ' ',
        -20
    )
),
-- your word
'word',
-- 20 words after
TRIM(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING(field, INSTR(field, 'word') + LENGTH('word') ),
        ' ',
        20
    )
)
```

)

Comment: if i have more than one word to do matching? what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Use the INSTR() function to find the position of the word in the string, and then use SUBSTRING() function to select a portion of characters before and after the position.

You'd have to look out that your SUBSTRING instruction don't use negative values or you'll get weird results.

Try that, and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to limit the number of words returned, however to limit the number of chars returned you could do something like

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field_name, LOCATE('keyword', field_name) - chars_before, total_chars) FROM table_name WHERE field_name LIKE "%keyword%"
```

- chars_before - is the number of
  chars you wish to select before the
  keyword(s)
- total_chars - is the
  total number of chars you wish to
  select

i.e. the following example would return 30 chars of data staring from 15 chars before the keyword

```
SUBSTRING(field_name, LOCATE('keyword', field_name) - 15, 30)
```

Note: as aryeh pointed out, any negative values in SUBSTRING() buggers things up considerably - for example if the keyword is found within the first [chars_before] chars of the field, then the last [chars_before] chars of data in the field are returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to get the result via SQL query and apply a regular expression programatically that will allow you to retrieve a group of words before and after the searched word.

I can't test it now, but the regular expression should be something like:

```
.*(\w+)\s*WORD\s*(\w+).*
```

where you replace `WORD` for the searched word and use regex group 1 as before-words, and 2 as after-words

I will test it later when I can ask my [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) if it will work :) and I will post it here